# Is it possible Mysql query by inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

i would get details from two MySQL tables

tables structure as shown

```
table:App
|AppID|AppName|AppType|

table:AppRelease
|AppReleaseID|AppID|ReleaseDate|ReleaseVersion|
```

and  written  query as shown below

```
$query="
  SELECT
    A.*,
    B.ReleaseDate,
    B.ReleaseVersion
  FROM       App AS A
  INNER JOIN AppRelease AS B
  WHERE A.AppID = B.AppID
";
```

i get the values when appid is in both tables

but i also  want to get values from App table  though i dont have data in AppRelease release table

is it possible to write query please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirement shouldn't be inner join.

Use left join:

```
$query= "SELECT A.*,B.ReleaseDate,B.ReleaseVersion
             from App as A LEFT JOIN AppRelease as B 
             ON A.AppID=B.AppID";
```